# Analyze multiple csv files in a folder and write ONLY the results to a single csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I can read and analyze a single csv file and add new columns to the same data frame. However, I cannot do that for multiple files in a folder and save ONLY the results to a single csv file.

I have tried like the following for a single csv file

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df1['Number of rows'] = (len(df1))
df1['Number of unique data'] = df1['column1'].nunique()
df1['Number of A type in Column2'] = df1['column2'].value_counts()['A']
df1.to_csv('df1_results.csv' , index = False)
```

But, I need the result like the following image in a csv file for multiple files in a folder:[Need result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiYPo.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the different csv files in your input folder, process the corresponding data and append the output dataframes to a list of dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
list_of_dataframes = []
path = "path to your csv files"
list_of_files = os.listdir(path)

for file in list_of_files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        df1 = pd.read_csv(file)
        df1['Number of rows'] = (len(df1))
        df1['Number of unique data'] = df1['column1'].nunique()
        df1['Number of A type in Column2'] = df1['column2'].value_counts()['A']
        list_of_dataframes.append(df1)
```

The only thing left to do is concatenate the list of dataframes into a single dataframe that you can then output to csv:

```
df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
df.to_csv('df_results.csv' , index = False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sheldon! If I specify the folder with multiple csv files as 'list_of_files' in your code then it gives 'IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '

Also, if i use 'df1 = pd.read_csv('file.csv')' then I am reading a single file not multiple files one by one. Thanks again. Sorry for the naive question

Comment: You may use `os.listdir()` to list all csv file in your folder. I edited my answer to show you how to proceed.